# How to map a Simics drive to access host filesystem or physical USB?

Tags: filesystems, host, simics

I've booted Simics to EFI shell on Intel EagleStream, but I can't get any drives to be mapped. I've tried setting $disk_image to an empty 10Mb .craff file, but still no luck. In QEMU, this is fairly straight-forward and one can even map physical USB slots on the host machine to a target drive. How would I accomplish this with Simics?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default disk image to an empty image, or any image, should work.  Provided it is the right variable (which varies with the target system in general).  Directly mapping a physical USB device into the virtual system is currently not a feature supported by Simics.

Comment: So how would I go about debugging this if $disk_image is not the right variable?

Comment: It looks like this was due to not having a SATA controller enabled in the bios softstraps. Could Simics somehow detect this and emit a helpful error/warning message?

Comment: Simics is a _simulator_ of the hardware and does what the software tells it to do.

Then, what is helpful to one user may be considered noise by another, so sorry, Simics should not be _that_ helpful.